# Powershell Unable to find type [Pester.OutputTypes] on VSCode Linux

Tags: linux, powershell, visual-studio-code, pester

I'm working on a [powershell port of Lesspass](https://github.com/edouard-lopez/lesspass-powershell) using Visual Studio Code on Linux Mint.

Test were working nicely from the IDE as of today.

#### From VSCode

Now When I'm on a test file and hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to run the test I got:

```
PS ~/projects/Lesspass/Lesspass> ~/projects/Lesspass/Lesspass/src/Password.tests.ps1


Unable to find type [Pester.OutputTypes].
At ~/.local/share/powershell/Modules/Pester/4.6.0/Functions/PesterState.ps1:8 char:9
+         [Pester.OutputTypes]$Show = 'All',
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Pester.OutputTypes:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

The Describe command may only be used from a Pester test script.
At ~/.local/share/powershell/Modules/Pester/4.6.0/Functions/Describe.ps1:234 char:9
+         throw "The $CommandName command may only be used from a Peste ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (The Describe comman\u2026Pester test script.:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The Describe command may only be used from a Pester test script.
```

#### From makefile

However when running my test with `make test` it works. The task is:

```
.PHONY: test
test:
    pwsh -Command 'Invoke-Pester -EnableExit (Get-childItem -Recurse *.tests.ps1).fullname'
```

Comment: Does Pester even have types?  If it's using powershell's class system, you need to do `using module`

Answer (score -1):

I think your issue is likely the fact that you are attempting to call a pester test script on it's own rather than via the `Invoke-Pester` Command.

I think that if you change your call to `Invoke-Pester -Script ~/projects/Lesspass/Lesspass/src/Password.tests.ps1` your error may go away.

The reason is that *.tests.ps1 files do not, on their own, know how to set up all of the background plumbing required to handle a test run. `Invoke-Pester` does a lot of set up before test files are run, and calling a test script directly with `F5` skips that setup.

If you want to be able to press `F5` to kick off a test run, what many PowerShellers do in VSCode is create a `debug_entry.ps1` file on the local system, and in that file put the command `Invoke-Pester -Script ~/projects/Lesspass/Lesspass/src/Password.tests.ps1`. Then when you want to start a run, you switch tabs to your `debug_entry.ps1` file and hit `F5` and your debug script makes the correct call for you. It has the side benefit of the fact that any debugging break points you have set either in the tests file, or in the code you are testing should then be respected as well.

I also think I should also point out that in your `make test` script, you are using `Get-ChildItem` to explicitly get all of the test file paths manually and pass them to `Invoke-Pester`. This is not necessary. `Invoke-Pester` by default will always search either your current working directory, or any path that you give to it recursively to find all test files available.

For instance from the output of `Get-Help Invoke-Pester` is the following snippet

> By default, Invoke-Pester runs all *.Tests.ps1 files in the current directory
>       and all subdirectories recursively. You can use its parameters to select tests
>       by file name, test name, or tag.

This snippet from the output of `Get-Help Invoke-Pester -Examples` demonstrates `Invoke-Pester`'s ability to search sub directories of a given directory, not necessarily the current working directory for tests to run

> -------------------------- EXAMPLE 11 --------------------------
>
> PS > Invoke-Pester -Script C:\Tests -Tag UnitTest, Newest -ExcludeTag Bug
>
> This command runs *.Tests.ps1 files in C:\Tests and its subdirectories. In those
>       files, it runs only tests that have UnitTest or Newest tags, unless the test
>       also has a Bug tag.

So in your case it would probably be easier and cleaner to change your `make` call to
`pwsh -Command 'Invoke-Pester -EnableExit`

That's assuming that your build system will set the current working directory to the root folder of your project.

Comment: You probably just need to restart vscode, certainly fixed my issue when I ran into the exact same error.

Whilst Invoke-Pester does do some clean up tasks before running tests, all it really does is run the .Tests.ps1 files.

Describe, it, context etc are simply Pester module functions and perform just fine whether run with Invoke Pester or not.